# SeekBar thumb states drawables not working correctly, not animating either

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I'm working for Android API 16+, testing on an API 21 device.
I'm using a `SeekBar` programmatically. I've got the following thumb `Drawable` defined in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <shape android:shape="oval">
         <solid android:color="@color/my_red" />
         <size android:width="18dp" android:height="18dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:state_selected="true">
      <shape android:shape="oval">
         <solid android:color="@color/my_red" />
         <size android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:state_focused="true">
      <shape android:shape="oval">
         <solid android:color="@color/my_red" />
         <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item> <!-- state_default -->
      <shape android:shape="oval">
         <solid android:color="@color/my_red" />
         <size android:width="0dp" android:height="0dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
</selector>
```

I apply this drawable using `SeekBar.setProgressDrawable`. What happens is that the thumb properly uses the default state drawable (as far as I know, the thumb does not show) but never changes. I tried to use `setSelected`, `requestFocus` and to just drag the thumb, but it does not change.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Based on a suggestion by @pskink, I changed my XML to try this:

seekbar_thumb_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
   <solid android:color="@color/my_red" />
   <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
</shape>
```

seekbar_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <inset android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_shape"
             android:insetTop="0dp"
             android:insetRight="0dp"
             android:insetBottom="0dp"
             android:insetLeft="0dp" />
   </item>
   <item android:state_selected="true">
      <inset android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_shape"
             android:insetTop="5dp"
             android:insetRight="5dp"
             android:insetBottom="5dp"
             android:insetLeft="5dp" />
   </item>
   <item android:state_focused="true">
      <inset android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_shape"
             android:insetTop="5dp"
             android:insetRight="5dp"
             android:insetBottom="5dp"
             android:insetLeft="5dp" />
   </item>
   <item> <!-- state_default -->
      <inset android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_shape"
             android:insetTop="10dp"
             android:insetRight="10dp"
             android:insetBottom="10dp"
             android:insetLeft="10dp" />
   </item>
</selector>
```

The result is extremely random. I was also expecting a small animation to happen, much like the default SeekBar animations, but it just changes drawables brutally.

My goal is just to reproduce a SeekBar close to the one of the YouTube Android App.

Comment: for testing, change `<solid android:color="@color/my_red" />` for each state with different colors, i am not sure if `<size>` is meaningful in that context

Comment: `size` seems to "work", as changing from `0dp`/`0dp` to something specific like `1dp`/`6dp` works, but not much happen when I interact with the thumb. I changed all sizes to `10dp`/`10dp` and now use 4 different colors, and I can see that the colors are changing. The default one, the pressed one and the selected one work, not sure what the focused one is supposed to mean (`requestFocus` does not work).

Comment: so if colors work it means that your drawable reacts on different states and `<size>` doesn't work, tried `<inset>` instead?

Comment: Can confirm, `size` doesn't work for transitions between drawables. I changed the `size` of the `selected` state to `18dp`/`18dp` and only the color changes. `size` however does work for the original thumb state. Trying other things like `inset`.

Comment: @pskink I edited my question. It does not work either, acts really random (like one to all 4 of the insets are set each time the thumb state changes...). I also think I'm missing something as the default SeekBar thumb is animated, and mine isn't at all. Where could I find the sources for the original SeekBar thumb drawable?

Comment: <sdk_root>/platforms/android-*/data/res/drawable/seek_thumb.xml